# Codeigniter image upload image (upside down for some images)

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I got a weird problem when uploading images via "upload" library.

When i have huge pics, like 1,8mb big it always uploads them upside down.

Otherwise it gets uploaded normally.

my model for upload looks like this

```
function do_upload() {

    $this->gallery_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../public/images');

    $config = array(
        'upload_path' => $this->gallery_path,
        'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png',
        'max_size' => 2000
    );

    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
    $this->upload->do_upload();
    $image_data = $this->upload->data();

    //to db
    $filename=$image_data['file_name'];

    $this->db->set('name', $filename);
    $this->db->insert('images');

}
```

could anyone please just explain why it gets like this? I've tried to increase max size to see if it would help but it didn't.

Would be more than thankful for some help :)

Comment: are you sure those images you upload are not upside down already? Try putting those images on another computer en open them to find out.

Comment: What @John said. I've never encountered something like that, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Some image viewers can read from the image meta and determine the position of the camera when the image was taken, so they will always show you the upright image. Try opening the image in a simple image editor like the basic MS Paint, Paint.NET, or GIMP from your computer if it gets uploaded upside-down, and see how will the image be shown.

Comment: Yes they are opened in the right position in image view, photoshop etc. What i realized though is that the photos that was uploaded upside down was taken with my iPhone with the phone rotated. Maybe this has to do something with the problem.

Comment: I am having the same problem, and have come to the same conclusion as @user1724347 . I guess the iPhone behaviour is correct in this case, and user-agents need to stop ignoring the Orientation part of the EXIF metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your config for upload:

```
$config['max_size'] = 0;
```